# cannot make :hover in nav

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to male that when you hover a "home" it will be a different color. Could someone please help me? Thank you!

```
<header class = "header">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-light;">
     <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                 <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:#b38b40;">Home</a>
                 </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: You need to move your inline `style=""` attributes to a separate stylesheet `.css` or `<style>` element because you cannot define `:hover` rules in inline `style=""` attributes _and_ inline styles takes precedence over rules from a stylesheet.

Comment: how can I write it in .css file?

Comment: Create a new text-file named `my-styles.css`, add some style rules, then add it to your HTML with a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="my-styles.css" type="text/css" />` in your `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your inline `style=""` attributes to a separate stylesheet `.css` or `<style>` element because you cannot define `:hover` rules in inline `style=""` attributes *and* inline styles takes precedence over rules from a stylesheet.

```css
header.header > nav ul > li > a {
    color: #b38b40;
}
header.header > nav ul > li > a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<header class = "header">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-light;">
     <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                 <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Away</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Life</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Is Short</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#">And Love</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Is Always Over</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#">In the Morning</a>
                 </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options,

1. create a new file - only for css, and put a link to the File from the HTML page.
2. write in the right row, style = "your style".
3. On the HTML page, write the label style